# how to read from port and write an exe file without coruption

Tags: c#, ftp, at-command

I am using AT commands and downloading a file using FTP . We have everything working until we send RETR a.exe .

The file data is also sent on the port. But it contains the response headers like RECEIVE:1,1400 , 150 connection accepted etc. How do we  write this file so that we will have a uncorrupted a.exe which will run on the client device. Please advise. We are using C#.  Should we remove the headers. How do we do it . Get a good exe file ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you remember to set binary transfer mode?

Comment: Yes . I have set binary transfer mode and also trying to use binarysteam to write. It writes bytes ( if original exe is 247 KB, the filesize we get is 241 KB sometimes , 237 KB sometimes. When we looked at the file, it has response headers like RECEIVED: etc. Since it is an exe, how do we strip off these headers and also ensure the entire data is read from port and written to file. Please help

Comment: private void GetBinary()
  {   
      BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(//a.exe);
   
         
   // do the retrieving
   int chunksize = 4096;
   byte[] chunk = new byte[chunksize];
   int count;
   IOException storedEx = null;
   
      try
   {
    while ((count = port.Read(chunk, 0, chunk.Length)) > 0)
    {
     writer.Write(chunk, 0, count);
    }
   }
   catch (IOException ex)
   {
    storedEx = ex;
   }
   finally
   {
    writer.Close();
   }